# Generating Multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do the following:
I'm calculating a series of functions which depend on one each other, meaning that they are calculated one after another.
One of the parameters in the calculation needs to be changed, and I'm looking for a way to create a new DataFrame with each iteration, by changing this parameter as well.

```
Tin_range = range(750,129, -1)
HTC_parameters = ['Temp','H','CP', 'RHO', 'V', 'MEU', 'Re', 'F', 'K', 'Pr', 'NU']
gas_flow = 0.1558 #this parameter will be changed to the following
Rgas_flow = [x for x in np.arange(0.1558, 0.1558*0.3, -0.1558 * 0.05).round(3)]
D = 0.09012

CP =[]
RHO =[]
V=[]
MEU=[]
Re= []
F =[]
K =[]
Pr =[]
NU = []
H =[]
Temp = []

def HTC():
    for T in Tin_range:
        Cp = ((0.2573 * T) + 1048.8)/1000  # J/kg*k
        rho = 0.000001 * (T ** 2) - 0.0019 * T + 1.1684  # Density
        v = (4 * gas_flow) / (rho * math.pi * (D ** 2))  # velocity
        meu = (0.0304 * T + 18.348) / 1000000  # viscosity
        re = (rho * v * D) / meu  # reynolds
        f = ((0.79 * np.log(re) - 1.64) ** -2) / 8  # factor
        k = (T * 0.00006) + 0.0257  # thermal conductivity
        pr = (Cp * 1000 * meu) / k  # prantel
        Nu = (f * pr * (re - 1000)) / (1 + 12.7 * (f ** 0.5) * ((pr ** 2 / 3) - 1))  # nusselt
        h = (Nu * k) / D  # local htc

        CP.append(round(Cp, 2))
        RHO.append(round(rho, 4))
        V.append(round(v,2))
        MEU.append(meu)
        Re.append(round(re, 2))
        F.append(f)
        K.append(round(k, 4))
        Pr.append(round(pr, 3))
        NU.append(round(Nu, 2))
        H.append(round(h, 2))
        Temp.append(T)

    return round(h, 2)
HTC()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Temp,H, CP, RHO, V, MEU, Re, F, K, Pr, NU)), columns=HTC_parameters)
print(df)
```

Comment: Where is `Rgas_flow` used? What do you mean you want to create a new DataFrame on each iteration? Do you mean a separate DataFrame per iteration? Or do you want to end up with one DataFrame? What should the output data type be? What is the issue right now? Are you looking for an improved method? Can you post an example of your expected output?

Comment: @ddejohn
thank you for your comment.
yes, i want to create a new data frame on each iteration. on each iteration i want the calculation to change, plugging in value of Rgas_flow, which goes in the calculation of v (instead of gas_flow, which is a plug number, i would like it to change according to the Rgas_flow array. out put would look somthing like this:
[data frame 1],[data frame 2]....etc

Comment: the issue now is that i don't know how to create a new dataframe, changing the Rgas_flow parameter in the functions